# Как установить webstorm в ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, java, webstorm

Скачал webstorm, распаковал его в `/home/user/`, запускаю `webstorm.sh`

> No JDK found. Please validate either WEBIDE_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

Полез в гугл, перепробовал все советы и все бестолку. Что сделать чтобы запустить webstorm?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get

Comment: @alexander barakin спасибо конечно, но я же вроде сказал, что в гугле был. Вот Вы можете сказать, что из этого всего по ссылке мне нужно?

Comment: вам надо установить **какой-нибудь** из *jdk-еев* и позаботиться о наличии переменной окружения `JAVA_HOME`. всё это описано по указанной ссылке.

Comment: @alexander barakin спасибо, действительно запустилось.

Comment: пожалуйста, опишите то, что сделали, в виде ответа. это может пригодиться другим.

Comment: @alexander barakin оставлю это Вам. Сделал всего-то - sudo apt-get update и sudo apt-get install default-jdk.

Comment: и ссылки лучше на русские версии давать - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-ubuntu-apt-get-ru

Comment: хорошо, напишу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

подробное изложение можно почитать [здесь](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-ubuntu-apt-get-ru).

---

кратко:

1. обновите список пакетов:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. установите мета-пакет `default-jdk` (по зависимостям будут установлены и *openjdk* и *openjdk-jre*):

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install default-jdk
   ```
3. в подробном изложении упоминается и установка переменной окружения `JAVA_HOME`. это может потребовать в каких-нибудь случаях, но не в данном, описанном в вопросе.

Comment: Ну фу же, Open JDK :C

Answer (score 2):

Я [писал](http://suvitruf.ru/2015/07/20/3798/) не так давно про быструю установку jdk.

Создайте скрипт с таким содержанием:

```
echo 'Install Java...' &&\
wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u66-b17/jdk-8u66-linux-x64.tar.gz &&\
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm &&\
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm/jdk &&\
tar -xvf jdk-8u66-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm/jdk &&\
ls /usr/lib/jvm/jdk/ &&\
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/java 100 &&\
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&\
rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer
```

И запустите его. Установит последнюю версию Oracle jdk.